# Remove trailing /connect string using htaccess (301 redirect)

Tags: .htaccess

```
example.com/x/connect
example.com/x/y/connect
example.com/*/connect
```

I'm trying to remove the trailing `/connect` and redirect to the URL excluding the `/connect`.

Can someone please provide the correct `.htaccess` code for this? I've tried but nothing works.

Comment: "I've tried but nothing works." - What have you tried? Do you have existing directives in your `.htaccess` file? This is a relatively simple redirect, so maybe there is something more fundamental that is preventing this from working?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to remove `/connect` from the end of any requested URL-path:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^(.*)/connect$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `/<something>/connect` to `/<something>` - removing `/connect` from the end of the URL-path. However, it won't remove `/connect` when that is the only URL-path. ie. `example.com/connect` will remain unchanged.

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the captured URL-path *before* `/connect` in the requested URL-path.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thankyou that works , brilliant. While you're here..
Could you also provide HTACCESS FOR THIS :

/bookkeeping?page=5& 
>> 
/bookkeeping?page=5

/*?page=*&
>>
/*?page=*

Basically : The pagination ?page=X& needs the trailing & removed.

Comment: @PaulWilliams You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: If you have another question then please ask another question. (That would seem to be quite a different question and requires a different technique. Also, formatting is lost in comments - I can't quite make sense of what you've written?)

Comment: I also am trying to remove "&reviews" from the end of all URLs.
If I use the above HTACCESS rule provided but replace with "&reviews" it does not work.  RewriteRule ^(.*)&reviews$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: If you have another question the please ask another question. That would seem to be a different problem (but it's not clear from what you've posted in _comments_) that most probably requires a different solution.