# htaccess to remove trailing /login from URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

For some reason Googlebot are crawling URLs with a "/login" at the end.

I'm trying to remove this trailing /login , 301 redirect with htaccess.

domain.com/login - this URL exists

but these do not :

`domain.com/*/login domain.com.au/*/*/login domain.com.au/*/*/*/login`
etc

Following is htaccess rules tried:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule (.*)/login$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please share your tried htaccess file in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: RewriteRule (.*)/login$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: That's great, please do add these rules in your question so that it can be clear to all.

Comment: `For some reason Googlebot are crawling URLs with a "/login` For your this comment, you mean you want to block urls ending with login? OR you want to redirect some urls? Could you please do explain more on this one, thank you.

Comment: EXCEPT for domain.com/login (valid page) i want to remove the trailing /login from all URLs (301 redirect) . Google visits URL like : domain.com/a/login and domain.com/a/b/login after it probably see bad code / links years ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing /connect string using htaccess (301 redirect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837350/remove-trailing-connect-string-using-htaccess-301-redirect) - Your previous question is identical. If you are still having problems then it's likely _where_ you've put the directive.

Comment: However, you need to find out why Google is crawling these URLs to begin with. Redirecting these URLs might just be masking an underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. As per description, this will redirect all urls which are ending with login and NOT starting from login.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login/?$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: When used in `.htaccess`... the regex `^(.*)/login/?$` (and `(.*)/login$` - the regex in the question) already exclude requests for `/login` (in the root), so the `RewriteCond` directive here is superfluous. (You are missing a slash from the start of the _substitution_ string.)

Comment: @MrWhite, that was just for safer side that it shouldn't match that uri which starts from login, let me edit it now.

Comment: My point was that this is no different to the original rule posted in the question.